# Spring quietly doesn't load config if Config classes have Builder and no default constructor. Why doesnt startup fail?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, lombok

I am facing a situation where a previously working config load stopped working after the Lombok builder annotation was added to a Config class.

What's more perplexing is that Spring doesn't even fail startup or even warn in logs about this.

Here is an example:

```
@Configuration
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.export")
public class ExportConfig {

    private String folderPath;
    private Integer capacity;
    private String filename;

    private Map<String, ExportClientConfig> clientConfigurations;

    public ExportClientConfig getClientConfiguration(String account){
        return clientConfigurations.get(account);
    }
}
```

Here, the `Map<String, ExportClientConfig>` usually gets loaded with all values from the `application.yaml`

However, once @Builder is enabled on the `ExportClientConfig` class, Spring quietly ignores the fact that its not able to construct ExportClientConfig during startup.

Relevant section of the `application.yml`:

```
app:
  export:
    folderPath: /data/app/export
    capacity: 50
    filename: data.txt
    clientConfigurations:
      ACC1:
        code: ACC1-ABC
        center: 1001
        payCode: SDLKFJS
      ACC2:
        code: ACC2-XYZ
        center: 2001
        payCode: DSFKHKSDJF
```

If the @Builder alone is reverted, everything works fine. Otherwise, the `clientConfigurations` map is empty.

Is this behaviour documented anywhere? Is this expeted in Spring or, is it a bug?

Comment: Isn't @Builder one of a Project Lombok magical annotations? How would Spring know and be responsible for stuff Lombok does? If it's documented anywhere, I'd expect it to be on Lombok rather than Spring side

Comment: What did you expect when you put @Builder at a configuration class of spring?

Comment: If Spring is finding matching class for filling this structure `Map<String, ExportClientConfig>` , and is finding matching data in application.yml and is unable to construct it due to lack of default constructor, then I was expecting it would fail at startup when building ApplicationContext

Comment: If Lombok is magic then what is Spring? Spring is even more magic? I fail to see reason for any attitude against Lombok.

Comment: But, based on your comment, it looks like this is the normal behavior for Spring. That's helpful - thank you!